# Changing icon offset based on zoom level

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to offset symbols of a symbol layer so that they don't interfere with a previous symbol layer (i.e. they don't overlap). I need to offset them as in both cases `icon-allow-overlap` needs to be set to true, as the symbols need to be viewable at all zoom levels. Ideally I'd like to do something like this:

```
"icon-offset": [
  ["zoom"],
  12, [-16, 0],
  22, [0, 0]
]
```

but that gives me an error:

`array length 2 expected, length 5 found`

Is there a way I can do what I want similar to what I was trying above? I know that `icon-offset` is not transitionable so that is why the above is failing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to use a function:

```
"icon-offset": {
  "stops": [
    [12, [-16, 0]],
    [22, [0, 0]]
  ]
}
```

More info on this can be found [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#other-function)